# How to create a window in smalltalk

Tags: window, smalltalk, visualworks

I am trying to make a window show up, but i keep getting a message not understood error.
The snippet:

```
Window new
  label: 'Hello';
  open
```

Comment: which Smalltalk are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cincom Smalltalk VisualWorks®, version 7.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for a game like that you want to use a custom control.  You start by creating a subclass of View for your game and override the displayOn: method to display the view.  You can add the view to the UIPainter canvas using a ViewHolder.  Set the View: property to be the name of a method that returns your custom view.

To intercept mouse clicks, you'll need to have a custom controller for your view.  You'll subclass Controller or one of its subclasses to create the Controller.  A method called defaultControllerClass in the View returns the name of the controller class.  In the controller, you can intercept mouse events.

I suggest that you load an example game to get you started.  Open the Parcel Manager, and select Toys from the list.  You should see SpiderSolitaire there.  This is a game written for VisualWorks that displays a custom view, does some simple animation on that view, and intercepts mouse events.  That should serve as a good example to use.

Comment: i get a path not found error, do i need to download some other package?

Comment: What were you doing when you got the error?  Loading the SpiderSolitaire game or some other step?

Comment: problem, solved, i had to download the package from the rep. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
ScheduledWindow new
    label: 'Hello';
    open
```

Or to open larger:

```
ScheduledWindow new
    label: 'Hello';
    openIn: (20@20 extent: 300@300)
```

I suspect, however, that this isn't what you really want to do since it's hard to work with a window that's built this way.  Can you explain more about what you want to do?

Comment: I wish to create a small game, like the reflex shooting game. You have to click at a sprite fast enough to get points.