# How to arrange views vertically with scrollbar in VisualWorks?

Tags: view, scrollbar, smalltalk, visualworks

I write RSSReader in Smalltalk so I have two Model classes: RSSModel (title, entries) and EntryModel (title, image, content, date)

I have list of EntryView  (inherits from UI.View) now I have RSSView and my displayOn method is going to display entries vertically with gap between each:

```
    | dy iView gap |
        gap := 5.
        dy := 0.
        1 to: model entries size
            do: 
                [:i |
                iView := EntryView model: (model entries at: i).
                iView displayOn: aGC at: 0 @ dy.
                dy := dy + 89 + gap]
```

and the result is:

[image: result]

I am not sure if I do it right way so If you have better solution for display RSSView please tell me.

Questions:

1. How to get height of entry? Now I write `dy:=dy+89+gap` where 89 is hardcoded height of entry.
2. How to enable scrollbars to scroll entries in window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the height of the entry?  Use:

```
"entry bounds height"
```

How to enable scrollbars?

To answer this, I'll first point out that the way you're getting the EntryView's displayed isn't really the best way.  You want to create a custom control like I explained in your other question [How to create a window in smalltalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295815/how-to-create-a-window-in-smalltalk).  You can use a CompositeView for the view and add each of the EntryViews into the composite using add:at:.

Once you have that, you can go to the Details tab in the UIPainter property editor of the view and turn on Vertical scroll bars.

Comment: But if I get entry bounds height it returns my system screen height, why?

Comment: Implement preferredBounds for your EntryView.  Check other implementations for examples.

Comment: That works but there are rendering problems:
Newly opened window looks as on image:
http://scr.hu/108/358z2
but when entry comes from from invisible part when scrolling it looks like that:
http://scr.hu/108/1x7r6
what might be the problem?